# How to obtain base iterator from boost::spirit::multi_pass?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, multipass

How can I access the underlying iterator that a `multi_pass` iterator is using?

Comment: `my_Iterator.shared()->input_` seems to work.

Comment: @llonesmiz: Oooh awesome! I figured I had to look at `shared()` but I had trouble going from there... would you mind posting it as an answer? :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying iterator seems to be stored in the `input_` member of the protected iterator member `member`. You can get access to it via the method `shared`.

```
my_iterator.shared()->input_;
```